# Nginx unpredictable redirect from https to http

Tags: rest, http, nginx, https

The frontend is written in react which make request via https to server with fastapi. Nginx is configured only for https connection.

This is my request:
https://www.site.ru/api/product/file/?city_id=979&producer_id=1
Also in body i am trying to send formData with file

Nginx redirect request from https to http and of course, fire error Mixed Content.

**Question is why nginx redirect to http**

I can't figure out what the problem is